# React pdf downloads blank

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I am using React hooks and the react-pdf from [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/)

I tried 3 different React pdf converters, and this is the one that has been working best so far. It still isn't working great tho - I can't see how to make it not either run out of memory or produce blank pdfs.

I have a component that produces the pdf:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet, Font } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

Font.register({
    family: 'Roboto',
    src: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i&display=swap'
  });

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: { 
    backgroundColor: '#F5F8FA',
    display: 'flex',
    // flexDirection: 'column',
    // alignItems: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    width: 555
  },
  section: {
    margin: 50,
    padding: 50,
  },
  reportHeader: {
    marginLeft: 0,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 24,
    lineHeight: 43,
    color: '#BF802F',
  },
  reportIntro: {
    width: 555,
    height: 132,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 30,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 22,
    color: '#0C3957',
  }
});

// Create Document Component
export const ReportPDF = ({ name, adviser }) => {

    return (
  <Document > 
    <Page style={styles.page} wrap={false}>
      <View style={{ textAlign: 'flex-start', marginBottom: 20 }}>
        <Text style={styles.reportHeader}>Your goals report</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
    )
}
```

And I have another compoonent that has a button to download the pdf file. I found someone else who claimed useMemo helps this situation, but I can't make it work this way either:

```
const stuff = useMemo(
        () => (
          <PDFDownloadLink document={<ReportPDF />} fileName="somename.pdf">
            {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
          </PDFDownloadLink>
        ), [])
```

I then have {stuff} inside a div in the JSX.

When I click the download link I get a blank PDF. What is happening?

If I don't set wrap={false} it runs out of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons this can happens is, pdf render before fetching the data. Therefore you can add condition before rendering the PDFDownloadLink to prevent this.

```
  !loadingReportData && <PDFDownloadLink document={<ReportPDF />} fileName="somename.pdf">
    {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
  </PDFDownloadLink>
```

(here loadingReportData is the state, which you set to true before fetching the report data, and set to false after the completion of fetching report data)